# SQL UPDATE statement with SET and WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-update

Here is the problem I need to solve: For each package of type Database, whose cost is over $400, increase the cost by 2%.

Here's my code:

```
UPDATE Package 
SET packost =(select packost + (select packost > 400.00*2/100))
WHERE pactype ='DATABASE'
```

Note: There are two rows with the type DATABASE. One row has DATABASE and has a packost of 380 and the second row has DATABASE and a packost of 430. I only need the second row to have the 2% increase

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: FYI: It's called `WHERE` **clause**, not statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For each package of type Database, whose cost is over $400, increase the cost by 2%.

This suggests filtering, not subqueries:

```
UPDATE Package
    SET packost = packost * 1.02
WHERE pactype = 'DATABASE' AND
      packost > 400.0;
```

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.  An error occured when I tried your code, what data type should I input in the ALTER statement to fix this? Sorry I'm just a student

Comment: @Kalos . . . Fix your data model!  Don't store values such as costs as a string.  That should be a number, probably `numeric()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, my problem has been fixed. Will remember everything!